# How to work with update_engine Unit test provided by AOSP?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-source, googletest, ota

We are planning to use google's unit tests for verification - https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/update_engine/+/HEAD/

I tried building update_engine like any other module -

```
mydir/update_engine $ mm
mydir/update_engine $ ./run_unittests
```

But on-page, it's mentioned like [building update_engine](https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/update_engine/+/HEAD/#building-update-engine) and [running unit-test](https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/update_engine/+/HEAD/#running-unit-tests) - I don't know to run these commands in my terminal.

I tried using `chroot`, but seems like it requires root access and that I don't have currently on my system.
If anyone ever tried these unit tests, could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I didn't get any answer or didn't find any Google document yet though I manage to run the **update_engine** unit test provided by Google. Below are the steps I followed -

- Build the update_engine by using `mm` command-

  ```
  mydir/update_engine $ mm
  ```
- Above command will generate binaries in out dir with `/data/nativetest/`
- Copy the generated `/data/nativetest/` into device's `/data/` dir.

  ```
  adb push nativetest /data/
  ```
- Run the unittest using below command with device connected-

  ```
  adb shell /data/nativetest/update_engine_unittests/update_engine_unittests
  ```
- That's all! It will output the result saying total 610 passed/ fail, you can see the complete report.

Let me know if you are facing issue, happy to assist.

Thanks :-) Happy Coding!!